# Como atrapar cualquier exception en c++ usando try-catch

Tags: c++

Hola estoy empezando a aprender c++. He tratado de provocar una excepción para irme familiarizando con el debugger que es code blocks. El método que tengo es el siguiente:

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

 int paquetes [50];

void ordenamiento(int arreglo[])
{
    try{
        cout << 50/0;
    }catch(runtime_error &e){
        cout << "error" << e.what();
    }
}
//Escenario 2 Manejo de estructura SWITCH
int main()
{
    ordenamiento(paquetes);
}
```

Intento que me imprima el exception en la consola pero no logro que eso pase!!.
En C# uno en el catch(Exception e) y con eso cualquier exception uno la muestra por consola o lo que uno quiera con e.Message o e.Tostring(). Eso es exactamente lo que quiero hacer con C++.

Comment: Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a [throw](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/)

Answer (score 4):

Las excepciones en C++ son **generadas por el propio lenguaje**; nunca podrás capturar una excepción que no sea generada mediante un `throw`. Es decir, un fallo de *hardware* **no** va a generar una excepción.

El manejo de ese tipo de problemas (*hardware*) son totalmente dependientes de la plataforma; en sistemas Posix, una división entre `0` generaría una señal `SIGFPE`, que podrías capturar estableciendo un manejador de señales mediante `signal( )` o `sigaction( )`.

Aunque el lenguaje proporciona algunas excepciones que podría **parecer** que si son generadas por el hardware (como, por ejemplo, [`std::overflow_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/overflow_error)), en la práctica están limitadas a funciones concretas de la propia biblioteca estándar: `std::overflow_error` solo se lanza en llamadas a [`std::bitset::to_ulong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ulong) y/o [`std::bitset::to_ullong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ullong).

La documentación proporciona una [lista de todas las excepciones disponibles](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception).

Answer (score 2):

Para capturar excepciones sin preocuparte por el tipo de excepción, debes usar la elipsis:

```
try
{
    codigo_sospechoso();
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cout << "Ha pasado algo terrible!\n";
}
```

La elipsis (`(...)`) captura cualquier cosa que haya sido lanzada con `throw`. Dado que en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) puedes lanzar **cualquier cosa**, no habría manera de saber qué variable poner ahí:

```
try
{
    switch (argc)
    {
        case 1: throw argc; break;
        case 2: throw "Horror!"; break;
        default: throw 'a'; break;
    }
}
catch (int valor)
{
    std::cout << "Error codigo: " << valor;
}
catch (char *mensaje)
{
    std::cout << "Error " << mensaje;
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cout << "Error desconocido\n";
}
```

Como puedes ver, capturar excepciones así no es muy útil ya que no puedes examinar la excepción, claro que tampoco habría nada que examinar si la excepción no fuese un objeto derivado de `std::exception`.

Mi consejo es que nunca uses la captura genérica (capturar elipsis) salvo que estés trabajando con código del que no tienes control; en su lugar: captura la excepción concreta que sabes que el código lanza o en algunos casos `std::exception`.

Comment: Resuemn, la elipsis captura todo, pero no explica, y no hay modo de capturar todo y explicarlo... (ando buscando como capturar errores no contenidos)

Comment: Cuando una excepción *flota* hasta lo alto de la pila sin ser capturada, se llama a `std::terminate`, puedes personalizar lo que se hará en ese caso mediante [`std::set_terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate), pero como bien dices, no tendrás información respecto a la excepción (u objeto no relacionado con excepción).